# Button click php/html run mysql query without refresh

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, html

This doesn't appear to work! nothing happens.

PHP FILE INDEX.PHP

```
<button class="buttonminus" onclick="minuswarmupset()" type="submit"  value="-"> - </button> 

<script>

    function minuswarmupset () {
      $.ajax({
        url:"minus_warmup_sets.php", //the page containing php script
        type: "POST", //request type
        success:function(result){


       }
     });
     }

     </script>
```

MYSQL FILE

```
 <?php include "../config.php"; ?>
    <?php include('../databaselist.php'); ?>

    <?php

    $query = "UPDATE users SET 

    `warmup_sets_today`=(`warmup_sets_today`+1),
      WHERE username='$username'";

    $result=mysql_query($query) or die("Query Failed : ".mysql_error());
    echo " ";

    ?>
```

Comment: Please, rewrite your question to help us to understand

Comment: What are you going to POST?

Comment: Where is set the variable `$username` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest to remove the comma from the query:

```
$query = "UPDATE users SET 

`warmup_sets_today`=(`warmup_sets_today`+1)
  WHERE username='$username'";
```

Answer (score 0):

First you must send the data to your php file

```
function minuswarmupset () 
{ 
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "minus_warmup_sets.php",
  data: { uname: "USERNAME" }
})
  .done(function( msg ) {
    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
  });
}
```

Then you must catch the posted values from php file

```
<?php include "../config.php"; ?>
<?php include('../databaselist.php'); ?>

<?php
$username=$_POST'uname'];
$query = "UPDATE users SET 

`warmup_sets_today`=(`warmup_sets_today`+1)  WHERE username='$username'";

$result=mysql_query($query) or die("Query Failed : ".mysql_error());
echo " ";

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the comma before the WHERE clause:

```
$query = "UPDATE users SET 
`warmup_sets_today`=(`warmup_sets_today`+1)
  WHERE username='$username'";
```

.. and prints a response. For example using **mysql_affected_rows()**:

```
mysql_query($query) or die("Query Failed : " . mysql_error());

echo "Records updated: " . mysql_affected_rows();
```